# Arch LinuxのGRUBの起動オプションからアンインストール済みのカーネルを削除したい

Tags: linux, virtualbox, grub

VirtualBoxでArchベースの`ArchLabs`を使っている者です。GRUBの起動メニューのデフォルトで新しいカーネルを使う方法が分からなかったので質問させていただきます。

ArchLabsを起動すると、OSのインストール時に設定したカーネルがデフォルトのカーネルとして設定されているようで、そのデフォルト(インストールする時に選んだ)のロングタイムサポート版のカーネルはつい先程最新のLinuxカーネルに置き換えました。そして画像のメニューから。`ArchLabs Linux`を選択すると「LTSのカーネルが無い」と警告を受けました。なので`Advanced options...`から入れ替えたLinuxカーネルを選択してOSを立ち上げているのですか、`ArchLabs Linux`メニューから最新のカーネルを立ち上げる方法は無いのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一応このようになった次第を説明しておくと、VirtualBoxではどうやらゲストマシンがLTSモデルを含む古いカーネルを使っていると5分程でマウス制御を受け付けなくなるバグを抱えているそうで、現時点でこれを解決する方法は最新のカーネルをインストールするしか無いようなので、新しいカーネルをインストールしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grub-mkconfig`を実行してGRUBのメニューエントリを更新してください。

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

[/etc/grub.d/40_custom と grub-mkconfig を使って自動生成する | GRUB - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/GRUB#.2Fetc.2Fgrub.d.2F40_custom_.E3.81.A8_grub-mkconfig_.E3.82.92.E4.BD.BF.E3.81.A3.E3.81.A6.E8.87.AA.E5.8B.95.E7.94.9F.E6.88.90.E3.81.99.E3.82.8B)
[【 grub2-mkconfig/grub-mkconfig 】コマンド - GRUB 2の起動メニューを生成する - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1902/01/news045.html)

デフォルト値を変更したい場合には、`grub-set-default`コマンドを使用します。

[【 grub2-set-default/grub-set-default 】コマンド - GRUB 2のデフォルト起動メニューを設定する - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1901/31/news048.html)